# mat-drawer styling on the right to take entire height

Tags: css

I have the following code snippet and I'm really focusing on the `mat-drawer` that slides out on the **RIGHT hand side**.

As you can see I've added the following styles:

```
style="background:white; width:600px; position: fixed; top: 59px; height: auto;"
```

However I'm not really liking what it is doing.  Especially if you move the browser to a smaller screen.

```
<div style="padding-top: 70px;">
    <mat-drawer-container [hasBackdrop]="true" >
        <mat-drawer #drawer mode="side" opened="{{toggleOpen}}">...</mat-drawer>
        <mat-drawer-content>
            <div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
        </mat-drawer-content>
        <mat-drawer #modalDrawer mode="side" position="end" 
        style="background:white; width:600px; position: fixed; top: 59px; height: auto;">
            <mat-card>
                <mat-card-content>
                <div>
                    <ng-template [cdkPortalOutlet]="selectedPortal"></ng-template>
                </div>
                </mat-card-content>
                <!-- Form Step Footer -->
                <mat-card-footer class="common-search-footer">
                    <button mat-button id="close" type="button" style="position:fixed; bottom:90px;" (click)="closePortal();">Close</button>
                </mat-card-footer>
            </mat-card>    
        </mat-drawer>
    </mat-drawer-container>
</div>
```

I have this layout in my _layout.cshtml The block above is part of the `@RenderBody()`

```
   <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top no-left-right-padding no-bottom-padding app-main-menu">
      <div class="utility-header hidden-xs" style="background-color: #EFF0EC; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; height: 70px;display:flex;">
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>
 
  <div class="common-full-screen">
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @RenderBody()   
  </div>

  <div class="common-flex-grow"></div>
  <footer>...</footer>
```

The issue that I'm having when I remove everything the position and height properties is that it get cut off at the point of the bottom of content here:

```
    <mat-drawer-content>
        <div><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
    </mat-drawer-content>
```

How can I get the mat-drawer on the right side to display all the way down to the bottom of the screen (and if moved to a smaller screen adjust appropriately)?

[image: ScreenLayout]